# Syncing terms with changed context via POEditor API deletes and creates the term

Tags: translation

In the project that i'm working in we use https://poeditor.com for translating strings.

When we synchronize terms via their API (sync_terms) it seems as terms that has a new context gets deleted and then recreated with the new context. This results in deleted translations!

We use a selfbuilt tool that scans our Visual Studio solution (44 projects in total) for translation terms. As context we set the sourcecode filename, for example SettingsView.xaml, which makes the translation a bit easier. But sometimes the sourcecode files are renamed and sometimes the translation is moved to another place which causes the context to change. And this in turn deletes the translation from POEditor.

Has anyone here stumbled across this behaviour? Their API documentation says nothing about this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. The translationkey + context is the actual key. When the context changes it also becomes a new translation. I'll now use the referencefield instead of context.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this ... good to know, as a colleague and I are starting to use POEditor.